# Não consigo deixar as imgs em ROW com flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Nao consigo colocar elas em row, apenas se eles estiverem width pra ficar todas do lado da outra.

```css
  

 *{
box-sizing: border-box;
}
 
#countainerslider{
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap;
width: 100%;
height: 560px;
}
img{
width: 600px;
height: 200px;;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id='page'>
    <header>
    
        <div id="containerimgs">
            <div id="containerslider">
                <img class="imgnav" src="imgs/image3.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates">
                <img class="imgnav" src="imgs/pepperonipizza.jpg" alt="pepperonipizza">
                <img class="imgnav" src="imgs/strawberry-chicken-salad-with-pecans.jpg"
                    alt="strawberry-chicken-salad-with-pecans">
                <img class="imgnav" src="imgs/burger.jpg" alt="burguer-bacon">
                <img class="imgnav" src="imgs/hotdogg.jpg" alt="hotdog">

            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main>
        <section id="service">

        </section>
        <section id="food">

        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <h3>Follow us :</h3>
        <i></i>
        <i></i>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editei a resposta, simplificando o exemplo.

```css
.row-nowrap {
flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

/* Flex Container */
.container {
margin: 0 auto;
display: flex;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<section class="container row-nowrap">
<img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates">
<img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates"><img class="imgnav" src="http://www.reasoft.com/tutorials/web/img/progress.jpg" alt="image-meat-tomates">
</section>
```

Comment: O que eu quero é que elas fiquem em apenas 1 row. todas, mesmo que saia da div. E elas funcionam desta forma se eu tirar esta declaraçao que disse, porém apenas se elas caberem dentro. como sao 5 imagens, nao fica em apenas 1 row. Tentei trocar position tambem

Comment: Entendi, agora ficou mais claro, você quer algo dessa forma? https://codepen.io/gferreiraa/pen/gEMmPy

Comment: Exato! Vou pegar como referencia. Muito Obrigado !

Comment: Consegui. Obrigado !

Answer (score 1):

Se vc quer todas as imgs na mesma linha o pai tem que ser `display:Flex` e `flex-wrap: nowrap`. Essa propriedade não vai deixar a linha quebrar mesmo os filhos somando uma largura maior que a do pai

Answer (score 0):

Coloque display:flex na div pai, no caso #containerimgs.
Ficaria assim:

```
#containerimgs {
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: Mas eu quero que fique em Row !!

Comment: confundi no código. troca column por row no flex-direction

Comment: Amigo já tentei kk